# What's wrong with my first Jquery code and how can I accomplish this event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I have a quick Jquery question .. This Jquery code is supposed to show red borders on the input text boxes if they are not filled at all after clicking on submit , this code is from book , I copied exactly the way the code is but I do not get the red borders at all , looks like it's not working ..

Also I'd like to give this code conditions during the validation process of the form.. If the ESN list text field is in the range of 1000 to 3000, I'd like the drop down to automatically  select STM3 below, if the range of the number input is between 5000 and 9000, I'd like Trackpack to automatically populate after a user let's say type 6000 on the text input  field .. How can I trigger the dropdown menu after typing a number on the text field?  Too tricky for a newbie , your help would be much appreciated.

```
<html>
    <head> <title> Form </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(':submit').click(function(e) {
     $(':text').each(function() {
      if($(this.val().length == 0) {
        $(this).css('border', '2px solid red');
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    });

    </script>
    </head>
    <body >
    <form id="provision">
    ESNList:    <input  type="text" id="ESNList" name="ESNList" size="30" /> <br />
    ESN Start:<input type="text" id="ESNStart" name="ESNStart" size="10" /> <br />
    ESN End: <input type="text" id="ESNStart" name="ESNStart" size="10" /> <br />
    UnitName:<input type="text" id="STxName" name="STxName" size="30"  />  <br />  
     Unit Model:   <select name="STxName">
    <option value="stx2">STX2</option>
    <option value="protopak">Protopak</option>
    <option value="stm3" selected>STM3</option>
    <option value="acutec">Acutec</option>
    <option value="mmt">MMT</option>
    <option value="smartone">Trackpack</option>
    <option value="smartoneb" >SmartOneB</option>
    <option value="audi">Acutec</option>
    </select> <br />
    RTU Model Type:
     <select name="rtumodel">
    <option value="globalstar">GlobalStar</option>
    <option value="both">Both</option>
    <option value="comtech">Comtech</option>
    <option value="stmcomtech">STMComtech</option>
    </select> <br />
    <input type="submit" value ="submit"  />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax error - a missing `)`

```
if($(this.val().length == 0) {
      ---^
```

Should be

```
if($(this).val().length == 0) {
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eqDRc/)

Comment: or even just `if (this.value.length === 0)`

Comment: @Zoltan .. Thanks man , you're great .. so How can I validate the form based on conditions and autopopulate the drop down based on input entered in the form .. For e xample , if I entered 1000 on the input text field ESNLIST , I'd like STM3 from the drop-down to be directly autopopulated .. How can i do that ??

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo (`$(this.val().length` should be `$(this).val().length`).

```
$(':submit').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(':text').each(function() {
        if($(this).val().length == 0) {
            $(this).css('border', '2px solid red');
        }
  });
});
```

A few thoughts:

- Consider, for readability, preventing the default (`e.preventDefault();`) before
  evaluating the input fields for length.
- Consider also using the
  more-specific `$('input:text')` selector (instead of `$(':text')`).
  [Benchmarking](http://jsperf.com/input-text-selectors) shows it performs much, much, better.
- Native JavaScript can replace the jQuery you are using to evaluate the presence on input field values and will [generally run faster](http://jsperf.com/input-value-js-vs-jquery); replace `if($(this).val().length == 0)...` with `if (this.value.length === 0)`

See http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/PvHGM/ for a working example.

Comment: Thanks .. I have another subquestion though .. I'd like to give this code conditions during the validation process of the form .. If the ESN list text field is in the range of 1000 to 3000 , I'd like the drop down to automatically select STM3 below , if the range of the number input is between 5000 and 9000 , I'd like Trackpack to automatically populate after a user let's say type 6000 on the text input field .. How can I trigger the dropwn menu after typing a number on the text field ???

Comment: Use the `onchange` event of the "controlling" `select` element.

Comment: Thanks for the hint .. but the book I have totally sucks .. doesn't even explain well .. can you give me a short example .. something that would trigger for example the option STM3 if I typed a number between 10 and 30 in the text field , like 15 ?? My book is horrible :(

Comment: It would probably be for the best to start another question specifically for this issue. You'll get "reputation" for the Q, someone will get reputation for the A, and the whole thing will be available for future reference...

Comment: ok .. Let me re-ask another question .. Thanks bro .. you're from france ?  I speak french :)

Answer (score 0):

A problem is you are not waiting for the page to load to attach your events.  This is easy to do in jQuery, simply surround the code in `$(function () {...});` as I've done below:

I also fixed a typo.

```
$(function () {

    $(':submit').click(function(e) {
     $(':text').each(function() {
      var th = $(this);
      if(th.val().length == 0) {
        th.css('border', '2px solid red');
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Comment: @PHP_lover - I also fixed a typo you were missing a `)` after `$(this`